# iOS scroll view bounds not equal to superview bounds

Tags: ios

I've got a UIScrollView that has constraints pinning it to the superview's leading and trailing edges (not the margins).  In this scroll view I have a UIImage which I'm setting to initially be the full width of the scroll view.  On the iPhone 7 this works correctly, the image is full width

However on the iPhone 7 Plus there is a gap between the edge of the image and the edge of the screen.  The scroll view is full width as when I zoom the image in it does go right to the edge.

I'm getting the image to match the scroll view width by setting

`imageView.frame = scrollView.bounds
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`

The issue seems to be the scroll view bounds.  On the iPhone 7 Plus the scroll view width is reported as 375, however the screen width is reported as 414.  On the iPhone 7 the scroll view width is 375 and the screen width is also 375.

Anyone know why this is?  I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something!

Comment: Where do you use that code to set `imageView`'s frame?

Comment: Both lines are in the viewDidLoad function of my view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your problem is that `scrollView`'s frame is not updated yet when you use it to set `imageView`'s frame.

Try to move layout code into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imageView.frame = scrollView.bounds
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to read up on the lifecycle of a controller

Comment: @TomReay `viewDidLoad` is called when view is created, but it is not even added to the hierarchy and you cannot rely on any frames there. In fact in iOS 10 all the frames aren't even equal to what they are in storyboards, they are 1000*1000 by default to force developers handle issues similar to yours.